# MS ACCESS with desktop application over LAN

Tags: ms-access, desktop-application, lan

What is the best way to host MS ACCESS with desktop application over LAN without using shared folder?

Answer (score 1):

You can use some Terminal Server (TS). For example Microsoft's Terminal server. It is a feature of server versions of ms windows OS. There are other TS available: Citrix, Nomachine.

When you use msaccess desktop application located at TS, your users connect to TS by some client ("Remote desktop connection" for microsoft TS) and works just like they are sitting at the server.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this answer? Right now it isn't clear what you mean by *use some terminal Server*.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi did i add enough explanations?

Comment: Yes, your answer is better now, thank you for editing it. I'm still not sure it addresses the questioner's issue (host MS Access with desktop app), but now your suggestion is clearer.

Comment: as i know there are only 2 ways to use MSAccess desktop app over network: shared folder (optional with splitting database) and terminal server.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I would consider doing it is with replication.  However, you should really try to use a shared network folder for the back end and then distribute a copy of the front end to each user.  Thi sis the safest way to use Access in a multi-user environment.

Comment: Native Access (Jet) replication has been deprecated for quite a while now. In fact, "Support for replication is fully removed from Access 2013." (ref: [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-Access-2013-bc006fc3-5b48-499e-8c7d-9a2dfef68e2f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)).

Comment: Ahhh.  I haven't used it since 2K.